# Sectioned UITableview: jump to correct section

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, indexing, sections

In a nutshell, I'm trying to use UITableView's index to shortcut to the first section in the table that begins with a character (a, b, c), where there are multiple sections beginning with that character.

**The approach...**

I have an array of section headings in a UITableView, where quite a few start with the same leading character; in `viewForHeaderInSection` I am placing the relevant section title drawn from this array.

I am then creating a second array, using `substringToIndex` to find the first letter of each from the first array, looping through to de-duplicate and using the results of that to place in my index list through `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`.

**The problem....**

...is that I apear to have lost the relationship between the index values in my list against their sections (I suspect a difference between saying one thing and doing another), ie. tap *'K'* and you get *'D'*.

Is there something that I can fish out of either array and plumb into `sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index` to link the index to the first in a common-char-based array of sections?

Thanks in advance.